# Insert a node at a specific position in a Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

This code is built to insert a `Node` into a specific position of a linked-list. It passes all the test cases for the interview, but I was wondering about the coding style regarding techniques, and especially variable naming, and any other best-practices you can help with.

```
Node* InsertNth(Node *head, int data, int position)
{
    // Complete this method only
    // Do not write main function. 
    Node * sentinel = new Node();
    sentinel->data = -1;
    sentinel->next = head;
    Node* node = sentinel;
    int i = 0;
    while (node->next && i < position) {
        node = node->next;
        i++;
    }

    Node* preNext = node->next;
    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = preNext;
    node->next = newNode;
    head = sentinel->next;
    delete sentinel;

    return head;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would have done it:

```
Node* InsertNth(Node *head, int data, int position)
{
    // Use a sentinel as this leads to simpler code
    // and no need to test for the empty list case.
    Node sentinel{-1, head};

    // Find the position we want to insert in.
    // Note: If there are less than `position` elements then
    //       the new element will be added to the end.
    Node* current = &sentinel;
    for(; position != 0 && current->next;--position, current = current->next)
    {}

    // Create the new Node and insert it into the chain.
    Node* newNode = new Node{data, current->next};
    current->next = newNode;

    // Update head.
    // In the case of null list or inserting at position 0
    // this will do something. Otherwise this is a no-op.
    head = sentinel.next;

    return newNode;
}
```

Notes:

1. Make notes of assumptions you have made in the comments.
2. I like the `for()` expression over the `while()` expression.
   It expresses my intent more clearly (ie that I am just chaining along the list).
3. No need to dynamically create the `sentinel`. By declaring it on the stack. It works better.
4. I have assumed node has a reasonable constructor to make the code cleaner.

Comment: You made assumptions about the available constructors of `Node`. A brace initializer might be more appropriate. Also there aren't any checks for the `position` parameter. I know my rewrite of the original version wasn't good. I'll try to reformulate my answer.

Comment: Minor nitpick: Also the `for` loops body `{}` could be simplified just using a `;`.

Comment: I hope you don't mind I've adopted your `for()` loop idea, though in a slightly different way.

Comment: Oops there's a major error: `current` can't be accessed outside the `for()` loops body! http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a4572250c4174ac

Comment: And another one found. Here's the fixed version: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27b656728fdfd900

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Fixed the errors.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Never use `;` to terminate a for loop. That makes code really hard to read because you can not tell if the `;` is an accident or by design. So **ALWAYS** use the `{}` even if it is empty as the intention can not be confused.

Comment: Usually I'm preaching _always use braces_ as well, but for intentionally empty bodies?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Yes even for empty bodies. `{/*Delibrately Empty*/}` is also acceptable.

Comment: I'll be (almost) gone here in another week ;-) ...

Comment: I've adopted your advice regarding the braces. What do you think of the OOP proposal in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you way overcomplicated that task. What you currently have can be rewritten in a few lines and with less variables.

Also your code will simply append a new node at the end of the linked list, if `position` is beyond the lists range.
So you probably should add some error checking for valid input parameters.

The use of `sentinel` as a `new`ed and `delete`d node will cover creation of a new list, but seems unnecessary overhead for me.

```
Node* InsertNth(Node *head, int data, int position)
{
    if(position < 0) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Parameter 'position' must be greater or equal to 0.");
    }

    Node * node = head;
    int i = 0;
    for(;node && node->next && i < position; node = node->next, ++i) {}

    if(i != position) { // position is a value beyond the list positions
        throw std::out_of_range("Parameter 'position' is out of range of the linked list.");
    }

    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->data = data;
    if(node) {
         newNode->next = node->next;
    }
    else { // Create a new head, list was empty, position was 0
         newNode->next = nullptr;
         return newNode;
    }

    node->next = newNode;
    return head;
}
```

---

> but I was wondering about the coding style regarding techniques

Returning the `head` looks a little bit odd. One would rather expect such function returns a pointer to the newly created node.

This would simplify the code from above even further:

```
Node* InsertNth(Node *head, int data, int position)
{
    if(position < 0) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Parameter 'position' must be greater or equal to 0.");
    }

    Node * node = head;
    int i = 0;
    for(;node && node->next && i < position; node = node->next, ++i) {}

    if(i != position) { // position is a value beyond the list positions
        throw std::out_of_range("Parameter 'position' is out of range of the linked list.");
    }

    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = node ? node->next : nullptr;
    if(node) {
        node->next = newNode;
    }
    return newNode;
}
```

---

> and especially variable naming

The name `sentinel` sounds misleading for me (besides you don't need that at all). A *sentinel* is some variable to survey a specific value like a threshold or such.
Naming that `tempNode` or suchlike would sound clearer for me.

Since `node` is used as an iterator on the singly linked list, I would rather name it `currentNode`.

---

Probably beyond what was asked in that interview, but the linked list should be a class that manages the `Node` structure, and `InsertNth()` should be a member function of the `LinkedList` class.
Also `int data;` could be a templated type.

Here's a sketch how it should look like:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class LinkedList {
private:
    template<typename U> struct Node;
    template<typename U = T>
    struct Node {
        U data;
        std::unique_ptr<Node<U>> next;
    };
    std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> head;
public:
    Node<T> const* insert(int position, T data) {
        if(position < 0) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Parameter 'position' must be greater or equal to 0.");
        }

        auto node = head.get();
        int i = 0;
        for(;node && node->next && i < position; node = node->next.get(), ++i) {}

        if(i != position) { // position is a value beyond the list positions
            throw std::out_of_range("Parameter 'position' is out of range of the linked list.");
        }

        auto newNode = std::make_unique<Node<T>>();
        newNode->data = data;
        // newNode->next = node ? node->next : nullptr;
        if(node) {
            newNode->next = std::move(node->next);
            node->next = std::move(newNode);
            return node->next.get();
        }
        else {
            head = std::move(newNode);
            return head.get();
        }       
    }
   // Other linked list operations ...
};

int main() {
    LinkedList<int> ll;
    auto newNode = ll.insert(0,5);
    std::cout << newNode->data << std::endl;
}
```

See a compiling version [**here**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a87d1278d7723a9e) please.

This will have the advantage that all dynamic memory management is done under the hood, and you don't have to care about memory leaks.

Comment: The reason for creating the sentinel in the OP code is to simplify the code especially in the case where the list is empty. Your revised version (of the OPS code) fails to take this into account. Now the code does overcomplicate the creation and use of the sentinel.

Comment: @LokiAstari My (second) code proposal covers the empty list case.

Comment: Your code does. But your simplification of the OP original code does not.

Comment: @LokiAstari Well, may be that _oversimplified_ the original code.

Comment: But the original code already handles the null head case (that is what the sentinel is for). Also it is well named; this is a common technique used to make the handling of `empty` list no different from the handling of the normal case (there are no need for special null checks when using a sentinel).

Comment: @LokiAstari But that additional creation and deletion of a node seems to be unnecessary overhead. My 2nd code proposal could be simplified further, if the function is defined to return a pointer to the newly inserted node (as one would naturally expect).

Comment: Sure. The new/delete is unnecessary. But the use of sentinel is good. See my example below for a better written version.