# Implementing a single linked list using smart pointers (replace std::shared_ptr with std::unique_ptr)

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, pointers

As an example code I've given [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/153166/52802), I have the feeling the use of `std::shared_ptr` is wrong and should be replaced using a `std::unique_ptr` because there's no real shared ownership semantics, besides of temporary needs.

How could that code be refactored correctly, e.g. using `std::unique_ptr` instead?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class LinkedList {
private:
    template<typename U = T>
    struct Node {
        U data;
        std::shared_ptr<Node<U>> next;
    };
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> head;
public:
    Node<T> const* insert(int position, T data) {
        if(position < 0) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Parameter 'position' must be greater or equal to 0.");
        }

        std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> node = head;
        int i = 0;
        for(;node && node->next && i < position; node = node->next, ++i);

        if(i != position) { // position is a value beyond the list positions
            throw std::out_of_range("Parameter 'position' is out of range of the linked list.");
        }

        std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> newNode = std::make_shared<Node<T>>();
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = node ? node->next : nullptr;
        if(node) {
            node->next = newNode;
        }
        else {
            head = newNode;
        }
        return newNode.get();
   }
   // Other linked list operations ...
};

int main() {
    LinkedList<int> ll;
    auto newNode = ll.insert(0,5);
    std::cout << newNode->data << std::endl;
}
```

I thought the move constructor of `std::unique_ptr` should cover all assignments of `std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>` variables well, but obviously it doesn't out of the box.

---

See the working code to play with [**here**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf40005d81bdc528) please.

---

I well know this question is kind of borderline here, since I'm asking how to rewrite that code properly regarding the constraints I'm setting up.

Though I don't get in which direction I have to go with that, as [all my attempts](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad0be74f415c3333) are failing so far. I think there must be an appropriate solution just using a `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can and should use `unique_ptr`. Several places will need to change of course:

Iterating through the nodes can use raw pointers:

```
    auto node = head.get();
    int i = 0;
    for(;node && node->next && i < position; node = node->next.get(), ++i);

    if(i != position) { // position is a value beyond the list positions
        throw std::out_of_range("Parameter 'position' is out of range of the linked list.");
    }
```

Use `unique_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr`:

```
    auto newNode = std::make_unique<Node<T>>();
    newNode->data = data;
    if(node) {
```

`unique_ptr` can't be copied, only `move`d:

```
        newNode->next = std::move(node->next);
        node->next = std::move(newNode);
        return node->next.get();
    }
    else {
        head = std::move(newNode);
        return head.get();
    }
```

Note that at the end, `newNode` has been `move`d from and is an empty state. You can no longer return `newNode.get()`. What was in `newNode` either ended up in some node's `next` or `head` by the end of the function.

Comment: That looks promising, I just avoided to use `get()` to refer to the raw pointers currently.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ raw pointers shouldn't be avoided as long as they don't _own_ anything. Only `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` should _own_ memory, but raw pointers can safely be used to access them.

Comment: `std::weak_ptr`'s to clarify semantics may be?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `weak_ptr` only relates to `shared_ptr`. The sort-of-equivalent of `weak_ptr` to `unique_ptr` is a raw pointer.

Comment: Well, I see. THX for your answer.

Comment: Well, I managed to get it compilable myself now: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a87d1278d7723a9e

Comment: I've adopted that finally in my answer to the original question.